# how event with if condition works in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
if(document.getElementById("ready_1").innerHTML && document.getElementById("ready_2").innerHTML =="Wait.."){
            document.getElementById("start").style.color = "black";
        }
```

I want to make `#start` `black` if `#ready_1` & `#ready_2's` `innerHTML == "wait.."`
not using jQuery.

Comment: Try not to use the DOM as your programming model. I'm guessing you have an asynchronous process that you're waiting on. Set some variables to indicate in what state your model is in. For instance: `process1_status = "loading"; process2_status = "loading";` Then your `if` statement becomes more sensibly: `if (process1_status === "loading" && process2_status === "loading") { .. }`

Comment: "wait.." is value after event happened

Comment: function readyOver1(){
   document.getElementById("ready_1").innerHTML = "Wait..";
   document.getElementById("ready_1").style.color = "red";
   document.getElementById("ready_1").target = "_blank";
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution is cleaner:

```
var firstReady = document.getElementById("ready_1").innerHTML;
var secondReady = document.getElementById("ready_2").innerHTML;

if (firstReady === secondReady && secondReady  === "Wait..") {
  document.getElementById("start").style.color = "black";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( (document.getElementById("ready_1").innerHTML == "Wait") &&    
      (document.getElementById("ready_2").innerHTML =="Wait..") ){
            document.getElementById("start").style.color = "black";
}
```

Like that?
Note that you used "wait.." in your explanation, and "Wait.." in your code.